# Angular + Material Table, how to implement aligned fixed width depend on cell content

Tags: angular, angular-material, tabular

I am trying to implement a dynamic cells table with Angular and Material to present semi structured data coming from a SQL like server. so will never know beforehand how many fields, or what the content of the fields and the size. just a JSON object, with 'key': 'value' structure.

So far I can create table and display the cells dynamically, however want to have cells with fixed width base the content of highest value length. since cells with numbers will occupy less space than strings with lots of text, but the table will still be tabular aligned.

Being played with [ng-style], but this is setting each of the rows individually and the table lost the tabular alignment.

Is there any way to format this automatically from md-table and CSS itself, or should I pre-calculate the proper width myself going through the records previously to display?

This is the HTML:

```
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
<mat-table *ngIf="data" [dataSource]="data" matSort class="" [ngStyle]="{'width': tableWidth }">

  <ng-container class="cell" *ngFor="let column of cells" [matColumnDef]="column">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{ column }}</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [ngStyle]="setStyles(row[column], column)">{{ row[column] }}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

here is the typescript to handle the styling on each cell content:

```
setStyles(cellId, cellValue) {
    console.log(cellId + ' : ' + typeof cellId + ':' +  cellId.length * 20 + 
cellValue);
let cellWidth = cellId.length * 10;
let cellColor = 'white';

if (isNaN(cellValue) ) {
  cellColor = 'cyan';
  cellWidth = 1000;
} else {
  cellColor = 'blue';
  cellWidth = 500;
}

const styles = {
    'background-color':  cellColor,
    'flex': '1 1 ' + cellWidth + 'px',
    'border': '5px solid red',
    'text-overflow' : 'ellipsis'
};

return styles;
}
```

Comment: set style on header

Comment: thanks, but setting style on header does not seem to drive the whole column